# Using /dev/rfcomm0 in raspberry pi

Tags: bluetooth, connection

I have paired two android phones to the Raspberry Pi 3. However when I attempt to execute a file it gives me the error:

```
[Errno 2] could not open port /dev/rfcomm0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/rfcomm0'
```

I have tried testing the connection using the Bluetooth Terminal from Play Store. It says that the device is unavailable.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You have to perform several steps in order to establish communication.

1. You have to pair your desired bluetooth device using `bluetoothctl`

   `sudo bluetoothctl -a`

   ```
   scan on
   devices
   pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   quit
   ```

   Where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the MAC address of your bluetooth device.
2. You have to create the serial device that binds to your paired bluetooth device.

   ```
   sudo rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 1
   ```

   The last number is the communication channel. It has to bee unique for all your connections.

Then you should be able to open a connection. (Assuming your bluetooth device actually supports the required SPP protocol.)